# create dropdown menu dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, menu

I had created a dropdown menu for my context menu item using a text that I had taken from some file.

the problem is, I don't know how I can do the coding part for these menus, I mean the menu is show truly but I don't know how to code it for doing something after click.

can anyone help me please?
Tnx.

More info:

I have a context menu which will appear on right click. In this menu there is an item which contains a dropdown menu, for example when you click file-->open and there is 2 options open video/ open music. so, I have that dropdown menu created during the codes, I haven't done it visually, so there is no for example "Private void openmusic_click" for me to write my codes in. I want to know where should I do the needed coding

Here is the code that creates the dropdown menu:

```
if (next > 0)
{
          string tex = playlists.Substring(here + 1, next - 1);
          Playlist_select.DropDownItems.Add(tex);
}
else
{
         string tex1 = playlists.Substring(here + 1, playlists.Length - here - 1);
         Playlist_select.DropDownItems.Add(tex1);
}
```

Comment: This question is too vague.

Comment: I have a context menu which will appear on right click. In this menu there is an item which contains a dropdown menu, for example when you click file-->open and there is 2 options open video/ open music. so, I have that dropdown menu created during the codes, I haven't done it visually, so there is no for example "Private void openmusic_click" for me to write my codes in. I want to know where should I do the needed coding

Comment: Provide what code you have attempted. Its currently very vague on how your doing it.

Comment: This is very vague or rather, very general indeed but, to help you get on your way, have a look at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding your text directly as an item in the DropDownItems property, you should rather instanciate an item object such as a ToolStripMenuItem:

```
ToolStripItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item.text = playlists.Substring(here + 1, next - 1);
```

Then you can add a click handler on that item

```
item.Click +=item_Click;
```

It would be something like:

```
    private void item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Your event processing logic here

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed. Still I need to work on it, but now I have the basic knowledge about this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a contextMenuStrip, there are several events you could use. See the link Sine Nomen posted in the comments for some Microsoft documentation.

For example, to add an event handler during runtime:

```
private void foo(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //The function to call when an item is clicked.
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    contextMenuStrip1.MouseClick += foo; // This adds foo as an EventHandler
}
```